# Does using variables for localizations in PHP have any drawbacks?

Tags: php

Are there any drawbacks using variables against arrays for localization of a project in PHP?

E.g:

en.php

```
$string1 = "Open";
```

de.php

```
$string1 = "Öffnen";
```

Comment: Can you do anything in programming without using variables?

Comment: Drawbacks compared to what?

Comment: Do you mean 1000 variables vs a 1000-item array? Do you mean variables vs constants? Do you mean variables vs gettext?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario Yes, comparing to arrays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see the drawback, that if you declare 1000 variables you have 1000 [zval containers](http://php.net/manual/de/internals2.variables.intro.php) with 1000 values. If you would declare it as an array like:

*en.php* :

```
$translations = array (
    'yes' => 'yes',
    'no'  => 'no'
);
```

... then just a single zval container is required (with a larger value portion of course). This will help to keep PHP's internal symbol tables smaller and save memory. If you ask me, use an array.

A more elaborated alternative would be to use the [`gettext`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php) extension

---

Just for completeness, another drawback would be that using variables for translations could lead to almost any imaginable variable name, and therefore is highly prone for namespace pollution. If you should use variables (for whatever reason, I don't see), then you have to "namespace" them to avoid this, like:

```
$translation_yes = 'yes';
$translation_no = 'no';
...
```

Comment: Once you start using `*.po` files you wonder why you ever cared with other formats.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario Always wanted to have a look gettext() but currently I have no project that requires this, but will do once. Btw, translated to german it means something like *.ass files.. :)